# setonkeylistner not working in my Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I almost wrote a book application and I want to pass volume key events,
when user press a volume key goes to next page but I've got issue nextPage method is not running when up volume button is being pressed.
I used setonkeylistner in OnViewCreated but it's not working and I don't know any other way.
my project has only one activity(MainActivity) with many Fragments

sorry for my bad English

here is my Fragment code

```
class ShowPoemBodyFragment : Fragment(){

private val viewModel: PoemBodyViewModel by viewModels()
private var binding: FragmentShowPoemsBinding by autoCleared()
private var shared: SharedPreferences? = null
private var mId by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
private var fId by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
private var size by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
private var sharedBackground: SharedPreferences? = null
private var sharedImage: SharedPreferences? = null

private val poemAdapter = PoemBodyAdapter()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentShowPoemsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.root.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { _, keyCode, _ ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {

            nextPage()

            return@OnKeyListener true
        } else
            false
    })

    binding.poemBodyRecyclerView.adapter = poemAdapter
    fId = requireArguments().getString("id")?.toIntOrNull()!!
    size = requireArguments().getString("size")?.toIntOrNull()!!
    viewModel.getPoemById(fId.toString())
    Hawk.put("lastSeen", fId.toString())
    Log.i("pomeid", fId.toString())
    mId = fId

    obserViewModel()

    var fav: Int? = null

    binding.markFavShowPoem.setOnClickListener {

        if (fav == 1) {
            fav = 0
            binding.markFavShowPoem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star)

        } else {
            fav = 1
            binding.markFavShowPoem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_bold)
            shared = context?.getSharedPreferences("shared_fav", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = shared!!.edit()
            editor.putString("id", mId.toString())
            Toast.makeText(context, "به لیست علاقه مندی ها اضافه شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            editor.apply()
        }


    }

    binding.textOption.setOnClickListener {
        SubDialogFragmentPopUp().show(
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,
            "popUp"
        )
    }

    if (mId == mId + size) {

        binding.nextPage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

    } else

    binding.nextPage.setOnClickListener {

        nextPage()
    }

    if (mId == fId) {

        binding.previousPage.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
     else {
    binding.previousPage.setOnClickListener{

        mId -= 1
        viewModel.getPoemById(mId.toString())
        Hawk.put("lastSeen", mId.toString())
        Log.i("pomeid", mId.toString())
        obserViewModel()
    }
}

    //Set Background Text
    sharedBackground =
        context?.getSharedPreferences("shared_background_color", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val bbcg: Boolean = sharedBackground!!.getBoolean("bbcg", false)
    if (bbcg) {
        val color: Int = sharedBackground!!.getInt("background_color", 0)
        view.background_show_poem_body.setBackgroundColor(color)
    }

    //Set Image
    sharedImage = context?.getSharedPreferences("imagePoem", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val image: String? = sharedImage!!.getString("image", "")
    context?.let {

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(image)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .into(view.image_poem_adapter)
    }

}

  fun obserViewModel() {
    viewModel.poemBody.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        when (it.status) {
            SUCCESS -> it.data?.let {
                poemAdapter.updatePoems(it)
            }
            ERROR -> {
                it.message?.let { requireActivity().toast(it) }
            }
            LOADING -> {
            }
        }
    })
}

  private fun nextPage(){
     mId += 1
     viewModel.getPoemById(mId.toString())
     Hawk.put("lastSeen", mId.toString())
     Log.i("pomeid", mId.toString())
     obserViewModel()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
            // Do something
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }
```

Try this and see

Comment: yes I tried this in activity but unfortunately it doesn't work in fragment properly or at least I don't know how to use it would you tell me please where should I put it in fragment or how to use it exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON to listen for volume button presses. You will have to Override the key event. Here is a [link that explains its use and why](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html)

Comment: it's too much if it's the only way I guess is not worth it